# Show postgis geometry transform point?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgis

I want to show my table with its id and its geom point.

I just can show geometry

`"010300000001000000040000009EDBE50D6862404000000000A06E5E407CCF473E0D9B3B4000000000002E5D407C535EB51A3A3C4000000000D02E60409EDBE50D6862404000000000A06E5E40"`

I want it show as I execute sql

`SELECT ST_AsText(geom) from gtest where polyname='ttttttt';`

result, e.g.

`"POLYGON((32.7688004848817 121.728515625,27.6056708264655 116.71875,28.2269700389183 129.462890625,32.7688004848817 121.728515625))"`

this is my jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" import="java.io.*" import="java.util.*" import="java.sql.*"%> 
<% 
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance(); 
    String url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/template_postgis_20"; 
    String user="postgres"; 
    String password="123456"; 
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password); 
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); 
    String sql="select * from gtest"; 
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
    while(rs.next()){
%>
    <%=rs.getString("polyname")%>,
    <%=rs.getString("geom")%>,//I want it transform to SQL:SELECT ST_AsText(geom) from gtest
<%
    }
rs.last();
rs.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
%>
```

My postgresql sql:

```
CREATE TABLE gtest
(
  polyname character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(Polygon),
  CONSTRAINT gtest_pkey PRIMARY KEY (polyname)
)
```

Comment: Um, what? What do you want to do? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to show geom using ST_AsText function

Comment: Er, use `SET_AsText` in your query? Just like you wrote? You have `SELECT  * FROM gtest;` in your JSP. Gee, I wonder if `SELECT polyname, ST_AsText(geom) AS geom FROM gtest` would work... (In other words: you've already shown what you need to do in your question, why don't you just do it? What're you asking?)

Comment: Yes,I just forget it.Thanks